# Python: Alternative to binascii b-function for predefined string

Tags: python-3.x, binascii

I want to use the hashlib function which requires byte-representation of strings. In this example from the Python documentation they solve this by putting a 'b' in front of the string:

```
>>> import hashlib, binascii
>>> dk = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', b'password', b'salt', 100000)
```

This only seems to work when the string is defined in the function call. I would like to use predefined strings but I cannot seem to use the b-function. I would like to do something like:

```
>>> import hashlib, binascii
>>> mystr = 'password'
>>> dk = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', b(mystr), b'salt', 100000)
```

Or

```
>>> dk = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', b mystr, b'salt', 100000)
```

Obviously, non of these worked. I researched and found some more complex solutions, but I wonder if there is any solution for predefined strings that is as smooth as for strings defined directly in the function.

Thanks!

Comment: What about simply `bytes(mystr)`?

Comment: @ByteCommander Thanks, that just about did it! I had to add an encoding. `bytes(mystr, 'utf8')` worked!

Comment: And this `b` you were talking about is not a function and is not part of the `binascii` module. It's a built-in way to create byte literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bytes(my_string)` or `bytes(my_string, encoding)` to convert a string to bytes. No need for the `binascii` module.

Documentation can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes

Answer (score 0):

So what did the trick was

```
bytes(mystr, 'utf8')
```